# fa-birthday-cake - anyone having trouble?

Tags: font-awesome

I'm using FA 4.2.0 and ALL FA ICONS are showing EXCEPT the "fa-birthday-cake".  I have copied/pasted its name to ensure no typos.  I've checked the file in the source and it's there.

Any ideas on what else to check?

UPDATE:  I'm using SmartAdmin template and the font files also needed updating, not just CSS.  My fault - all good now!